# variable amount of data receive using recv() in perl

Tags: perl, recv

How to receive data on server1,server2,server3 which is send from proxy1,proxy2,proxy3 respectively because it is not fixed amount of data it may change?

```
$proxy2=IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerPort=>'5431',Proto=>'UDP',PeerAddr=>'127.0.0.1');
$proxy3=IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerPort=>'5430',Proto=>'UDP',PeerAddr=>'127.0.0.1');
$proxy4=IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerPort=>'5429',Proto=>'UDP',PeerAddr=>'127.0.0.1');

$b=0;
while($b<10){
  $ascii=ord($msg1[$b]);

  if($ascii>48 && $ascii<59){
    print ("ASCII=".$ascii);
    print ("It is an number.\n");
    $proxy2->send("$ascii");
  }
  elsif($ascii>64 && $ascii<91  ||  $ascii>96 && $ascii<123){
    print ("ASCII=".$ascii);
    print ("It is an alphabet.\n");
    $proxy3->send("$ascii");
  }
  else{
    print ("ASCII=".$ascii);
    print ("It is a character.\n");
    $proxy4->send("$ascii");
  }
  $b++;
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: the problem i am getting is that when i write code of server1 to recieve values from proxy2 using recv() command ,the server1 don't know how much values are send from proxy2 because the value of variable ascii which are send may change because i am taking input. Basically I am new to perl programming.. Any small help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you state, is that the receiving socket does not know how much data there is to read. The solution is a convention that uses additional data to tell the receiving socket how much data there is to read, kind of like the `Content-length` header in an HTTP message.

You are typically sending small packets (values between "0" and "255"?), so how about you precede each message with the length of the message in bytes?

```
$proxyN->send(length($ascii) . "$ascii");
```

On the receiving end, you'll do two `recv` calls. The first one for a single byte. The second one for the number of bytes specified in the first call.

```
$receiver->recv($count, 1);
$receiver->recv($value, $count);
```

This scheme will work for payloads up to 9 bytes in length. If your payload could be up to 255 bytes, you would encode the length as an 8-bit integer (say, using `chr(length($message))`) on the sender and decode it (e.g., `$len=ord($count)`) on the receiver. If the message could be even longer, you'll want to look into `pack` and related functions to encode larger integer values into a few bytes of memory.